# C++ ¿Por que sale la advertencia C6262?

Tags: c++

[image: Este es el codigo y la advertencia]

En visual studio, con este código me ha salido esta advertencia y no solo con este también con otros y no se el porque de esto.

En mi computadora antigua nunca me había salido esta advertencia ¿Tiene que ver con la configuración del Visual Studio? Como puedo quitar de manera definitiva esa advertencia?

Comment: Por favor, para futuras preguntas no pongas imágenes. Copia y pega el código y, si es necesario, entonces ya si añade una captura de pantalla ... piensa que la captura de pantalla debería ser un complemento, no una parte imprescindible de la pregunta

Comment: Cómo puedes ver es solo una advertencia. No necesitas preocuparte por ello. El stack por defecto reserva 1MB. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/f-set-stack-size

Answer (score 3):

Este array:

```
int numeros[100][100];
```

Consume el solito 100 * 100 * 4 = 40.000 Bytes

Hay que tener mucho cuidado al declarar arrays ya que los mismos se van a crear en la pila del programa.

La pila del programa es una región de memoria que el propio programa va a utilizar para varios propósitos:

- Declaración de variables locales
- Seguimiento de la ejecución entre funciones

Esta región de memoria suele tener un tamaño bastante reducido, sobretodo si lo comparamos con la cantidad de memoria RAM de la que dispone un equipo moderno. El problema que nos podemos encontrar al abusar de la pila es que si se llena, el programa literalmente morirá.

Es por este motivo que VS te está avisando. La advertencia simplemente te está poniendo en alerta porque lo normal es que los programas, sobretodo cuando crecen en complejidad, empiecen a tener llamadas a múltiples funciones, y en ese caso es muy probable que llenes la pila y el programa termine abruptamente.

Si necesitas hacer un uso intensivo de memoria es preferible acudir a la memoria dinámica. En comparación con la pila es literalmente infinita:

```
int ** numeros = new int*[100];
for( int i=0; i<100; i++ )
    numeros[i] = new int[100];

// ...

for( int i=0; i<100; i++ )
    delete[] numeros[i];

delete[] numeros;
```

Comment: mmmmm
Ya que en mi laptop antigua no me salia esta advertencia y en esta si eso quiere decir   mi laptop actual tiene una pila menor o mas bien una menor capacidad de memoria?

Comment: @Programadornovato la generación de advertencias es responsabilidad del compilador.  Si el portátil es antiguo seguramente tendrás instalado en el mismo un compilador diferente, por lo que las advertencias pueden variar

Answer (score -1):

La advertencia no tiene que ver con tu ordenador nuevo, si no con la configuración de VS.

Con una rápida busqueda en Google del códio de advertencia, puedes leer más detalles sobre el problema y como arreglarlo: [Microsoft docs - C6262](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/code-quality/c6262?view=msvc-170)

En resumen lo que te está diciendo es que la función que has programado esta guardando en la [pila](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pila_de_llamadas) más bytes que los establecidos en el límite por defecto que son 16KB.

Para cambiarlo y que no te salga la advertencia:

> 1. En el IDE de Visual Studio, seleccione el proyecto en la ventana
>    Explorador de soluciones.
> 2. En la barra de menús, seleccione **Proyecto>Propiedades.**
> 3. En el cuadro de diálogo Páginas de propiedades, seleccione la página de propiedades **Propiedades> de configuraciónC/C++>Línea de
>    comandos**.
> 4. En **Opciones adicionales**, agregue /analyze:stacksize , donde  es mayor que constant_1. Por ejemplo, si
>    constant_1 es 27180, puede escribir /analyze:stacksize 32768. Elija
>    Aceptar para guardar los cambios.

Comment: Esto solo consigue quitar la advertencia, pero es un consejo terrible. Es como apagar la alarma contra incendios porque suena mucho.

Comment: Ya intente eso pero me sigue saliendo la advertencia